# React Native SectionList different data structure. Type FirstObject is not assignable to SecondObject

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm using React Native SectionList with different data structure with the following below

```
const firstObject: FirstObject = [{
    id: 1,
    age: null,
    breed: null,
    gender: 'female',
    isCastrated: false,
    isCrossbreed: false,
  },
  ...
]

const secondObject: SecondObject = [{
  id: 1,
  text: "qwrqwr12r",
  callDuration: 15,
  callAt: "2022-12-22T11:09:07Z",
  completionDeadline: "2022-12-24T11:09:07Z",
  consultationFreeLength: 1,
  },
  ...
]
```

It works but I got a typescript error that I can't figure out? And it seems it only allowed 1 typing for the section data. What I need is every data from the section must be different. For now we only have 2 and its default the FirstObject and SecondObject its not dynamic

```
    No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: SectionListProps<SecondObject, DefaultSectionT> | Readonly<SectionListProps<SecondObject, DefaultSectionT>>): SectionList<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'FC<ListRenderItemInfo<FirstObject>>' is not assignable to type 'SectionListRenderItem<SecondObject, DefaultSectionT>'.
      Types of parameters 'props' and 'info' are incompatible.
        Type 'SectionListRenderItemInfo<SecondObject, DefaultSectionT>' is not assignable to type 'ListRenderItemInfo<FirstObject>'.
          Types of property 'item' are incompatible.
            Type 'SecondObject' is missing the following properties from type 'FirstObject': userId, name, speciesId, speciesOther, and 9 more.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: SectionListProps<SecondObject, DefaultSectionT>, context: any): SectionList<SecondObject, DefaultSectionT>', gave the following error.
    Type 'FC<ListRenderItemInfo<FirstObject>>' is not assignable to type 'SectionListRenderItem<SecondObject, DefaultSectionT>'.ts(2769)
```

My section list

```
  <SectionList
    style={styles.container}
    contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
    ListEmptyComponent={<TranslatedNoData onClick={refetch} />}
    scrollEventThrottle={16}
    bouncesZoom={false}
    maxToRenderPerBatch={8}
    removeClippedSubviews
    refreshControl={<FlatListRefreshControl refreshing={isFetching} onRefresh={refetch} />}
    sections={[
      {
        data: [],
        title: 'FirstObject',
        keyExtractor: ({id}) => id.toString(),
        renderItem: FirstObjectItem, // <- Error, If I removed the object below it works.
        ItemSeparatorComponent: () => <Box pt="12px" />,
      },
      {
        data: currentData?.data || [],
        title: 'SecondObject',
        keyExtractor: ({id}) => id.toString(),
        renderItem: SecondObjectItem,
        ItemSeparatorComponent: () => <Box pt="12px" />,
      },
    ]}
    renderSectionFooter={() => <Box h="32px" />}
    renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => <Text>{title}</Text>}
    onScroll={
      scrollOffsetY &&
      Animated.event([{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: scrollOffsetY}}}], {useNativeDriver: false})
    }
  />
```

My two components

```
const FirstObjectItem: FC<ListRenderItemInfo<FirstObject>> = ({item}) => {
   ...
});
const SecondObjectItem: FC<ListRenderItemInfo<SecondObject>> = ({item}) => {
   ....
});
```